# How to hold the lens cap?

Tags: equipment-protection, lens-cap

When I'm using my compact digital camera, what is the best way to hold the lens cap.

My lens cap is attached to the camera with a lace to avoid losing it. This is convenient, but when recording videos, the lens cap impact with the camera records a 'tik-tock' sound in the audio.

Comment: Stick it in some pocket? (trousers, jacket bag)

Comment: It's worth noting that at least I have never seen a SLR with a lens cap attached to the lens in any way (when not actually used to protect the front lens, that is). I do think that says something about how big a problem this is in practice for serious photographers.

Comment: Why not using a LONGER lace ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I highly recommend detaching it from the camera and storing it in a bag or a pocket while you are using your camera.

It swings around too much and it gets in the way a lot.

Having the take the cap off and put it back on also slows you down. So, once you have taken it off, only put it back on the camera when you are 100% sure you won't be needing your camera for a fairly extended period of time. For me, I usually do that no earlier than when I am packing up and leaving the place.

Comment: But there is a possibility of loosing it. :( I'm more of a travel photographer.

Comment: The possibility of loosing something that costs $2 doesn't worry me a whole lot. I have only ever lost **one** lens cap throughout the years.

Comment: My experience is much worse than @Gapton's -- I've lost *two* front lens caps throughout the years! (Rear lens caps are another story; I lose one of those almost every year it seems.)

Comment: I've only lost 1, but it was in a porta-potty. :-(

Comment: When I'm travelling, and I'm in Bali at the moment, I always pack a spare set of caps, front and back, for all of my lenses. I've never lost one but just in case.

Answer (score 3):

If your camera has a shoulder strap or a neck strap, another way would be attaching the cap to the strap using a cap holder ([see this link](http://www.cameracapholder.com) to get an idea of what I am talking, but you might want to look for something that fits your cap) - or making a DIY of something similar.

If your camera doesn't have a wide strap, you might find something similar for a wrist strap too - but even if you do find/make a DIY, I think that will be very inconvenient to hold. In that case, as @Gapton suggested, putting it away in a pocket or bag is a better idea.

Comment: This seems a **great idea**

Comment: I'm glad you like it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Put it in your pocket - make an habit out of it, when you take the lens cap off you immediately put it in your right pocket (or whatever pocket is more convenient for you, obviously) that way it doesn't get in the way and you always know where it is.

And if you lose the lens cap you can get a new one on eBay from China for less than $2 (including shipping) that works just as well as the original.

Answer (score 2):

On cameras with detachable lens cap, I make a discipline of taking it off and immediately putting it in my pocket.  When I don't do this, eventually I get disctracted and end up losing the lens cap.

One thing to consider is which way you put it in your pocket.  I put it so that the inside of the cap faces outward.  There is a range of weather conditions and activities you can be doing where moisture from your body ends up condensing on the lens cap.  If this happens and you put the cap back on, you have just sealed in some moisture between the lens and that cap.  That can't be good, and in some cases will fog the front of the lens so you have to wait to use it for the fog to clear when you take the cap off again.

Also always take a quick look at the inside of the lens cap before putting it back on the lens.  Figure any dirt there can end up on the lens.  Give it a quick blow if you have to, being careful not to actually spit on it.

In general, be mindful of the fact that the inside of the lens cap should be considered a clean zone.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind staining your camera with adhesive, you an adhere a small piece of velcro to the cap and to the bottom of the camera (for example) so you can stick it while recording.

Another option that will save your camera is to get a bolt that fits the tripod mount thread and use it to attach a thin piece of plastic, metal or wood and stick the velcro to that thing insteat of your camera's body.

If you bolt a steel or iron piece to the tripod mount, you can use a magnet to adhere the cap to it, most cameras won't mind a small magnet under them.

Yet another option is to get a small wrist band and use it exclusively for the lens cap. I'm thinking if the same kind that you would use with the camera itself, but my suggestion is to use a separate one for the cap, so you can hang it on your hand further from the camera. When you dont need it to be separated, just tie or interlace the two wrist bands together or join them ising a chain ring, a small clip, hook or something alike.

Answer (score -3):

i have bought this one for my phone for work since phone companies keep making phones for blind people bigger and bigger i got this to put my phone in when im working works great this one comes with extended belt for people that have big waist [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01K1ZNFXC/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K1ZNFXC)

or you may want try this one i have yet to try yet handcuff holder , tape measure holder you can buy on amazon.com

Comment: Unrelated to the question at 99.9 %. Flagged as "not an answer".